# Mailing default error page in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade, illuminate-container

On production server i would like to send myself an email every time an error ocurres. I'm now sending a basic mail but i would like to attach the rendered basic (orange) error page as a attached html file.

Any idea how to do that?

This is what i currently have:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    Log::error($exception);

    $data = array('exception' => $exception);
    Mail::send('emails.error', $data, function($message)
    {
        $message->from(Config::get('app.debug_email'));
        $message->to(Config::get('app.debug_email'))->subject(Config::get('app.client_name') . ' Error');
    });

    if (!Config::get('app.debug')) {
        return Response::view('errors.index', $code);
    }
});
```

Comment: The `Whoops` output will not work in an email. Typically, the backtrace information shown is stored in your logs in plain text.

Answer (score 1):

You really wouldn't want to do that to be honest, as emails do not generally support CSS, which is what that page uses.

You are best off just having the data emailed that contains the backtrace, the url and any input given so you can reproduce the error.

Comment: I would send html as an attachment. Since all css is inline that should not be a problem i guess...

Comment: @JannickVandaele All the information presented there is available in the plain-text backtrace.

Comment: And how do i get the plain text backtrace? It's not in $exception